# C# cannot programmatically get a user domain given the SID

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to extract all the users that have a security rule to a certain folder, to do that I'm using a C# application, however I'm having trouble getting the correct domain for the user.

Let's say that I'm on domain CURRENT, but some users that have access to the folder are also on the domain OLD. Between the domain there's a trust. However some users that have been migrated from OLD to CURRENT for some reason appear to be on CURRENT when I lookup their SID. The strange thing however is that windows explorer correctly shows them to be on domain OLD.

### The code

```
public IdentityReference GetUser(string SID)
{
    return ( new NTAccount(SID) ).Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
}
```

As you can see, it gets the SID of the user and returns the NTAccount (DOMAIN\user). To get the SID I use the following code:

```
DirectorySecurity ACL = Directory.GetAccessControl(folder);
AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = ACL.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
{
    IdentityReference user = GetUser(rule.IdentityReference.value);
    //do stuff ...
}
```

I also have a PowerShell script that does the same thing:

```
echo (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

### The problem

Now, I have user OLD\user1, that is, however, also present in the new domain as CURRENT\user1. When I right click on windows explorer it correctly shows me the user as OLD\user1, but when I run the C# code it always gives me CURRENT\user1, which is not what I want.

Strangely enough, when I try to do the same thing in PowerShell, the user is also correctly identified as OLD\user1. Even more strangely, if I run the PowerShell script and only then I run the C# code I get the correct result, however after exactly 10 minutes the C# code is wrong again.

### What I have already tried

Given these information, I figured out that it must be a sort of caching problem (as it also seem to happen to other people) <strike>and also that for some reason C# and PowerShell handle the lookup request in a different way,</strike>(See **EDIT1** down below) so I've tried the following:

- Running PowerShell code from inside C#

  ```
  PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
  ps.AddScript("New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(\""+SID+"\")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]");
  return (IdentityReference)(ps.Invoke()[0].BaseObject);
  ```
- Running the same script saved on the same folder as the executable from within the exe

  ```
  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-File \"{0}\" {1}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\get_user.ps1", SID);
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  p.Start();

  p.WaitForExit();
  return (new NTAccount(output)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
  ```
- Using P/Invoke to do the lookup with the WIN32API

  ```
  enum SID_NAME_USE
  {
      SidTypeUser = 1,
      SidTypeGroup,
      SidTypeDomain,
      SidTypeAlias,
      SidTypeWellKnownGroup,
      SidTypeDeletedAccount,
      SidTypeInvalid,
      SidTypeUnknown,
      SidTypeComputer
  }

  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool LookupAccountSid(
                        string lpSystemName,
                        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] Sid,
                        StringBuilder lpName,
                        ref uint cchName,
                        StringBuilder ReferencedDomainName,
                        ref uint cchReferencedDomainName,
                        out SID_NAME_USE peUse);

  byte[] sid = { /* the SID in bytes */ };
  StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
  uint cchName = (uint)name.Capacity;
  StringBuilder referencedDomainName = new StringBuilder();
  uint cchReferencedDomainName = (uint)referencedDomainName.Capacity;
  SID_NAME_USE sid_use;

  LookupAccountSid(null, sid, name, ref cchName, referencedDomainName, ref cchReferencedDomainName, out sid_use);

  if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 0)
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Account({0}): {2}\\{3}", sid_use, "...", referencedDomainName.ToString(), name.ToString()));
  ```

But none of these solved the issue. Please also note that changing the server caching option is not really a solution, as I'm not able to do that.

### **EDIT1:**

Apparently, it's not correct that PowerShell handles the request in a different way, what I forgot to mention is that in the PS code, before requesting the NTAccount from the SID, I did the reverse: I first requested the SID from the NTAccount, like this:

```
echo (New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("OLD\user1")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
echo (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

And this must have triggered the cache, so it most definitely is a caching problem.

### **EDIT2**

I've managed to "solve" the issue by moving the executable to a computer under the OLD domain (as this is where the place where it should have carried out its task remotely from another machine), but I will leave the question unsolved as it is not really the best solution.

Comment: do you have more then one dc? are they replicated correctly?

Comment: Maybe the AD `sIDHistory` attribute of the **current\user1** could help you to get the **old\user1**